# Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: failed to open db:

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, chainlink

When I "**chainlink node start**",
I get the error:

"Cannot boot Chainlink: opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=/private/tmp user=myname database=`: server error (FATAL: unrecognized configuration parameter "?application_name" (SQLSTATE 42704))"

I follow this youtube video: https://youtu.be/ZB3GLtQvgME?t=2017
I have a .env
but it is not reading from there.
No matter what I change on DATABASE_URL,
I get the same error.

```
ETH_URL=wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/ 
FEATURE_EXTERNAL_INITIATORS=true 
LOG_LEVEL=debug 
ETH_CHAIN_ID=42 
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2 
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS= 
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0 
SECURE_COOKIES=false 
ALLOW_ORIGINS=* 
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost:5432/kovan_demo?sslmode=disable 
DATABASE_TIMEOUT=0 
FEATURE_FLUX_MONITOR=true 
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT=0 
CHAINLINK_DEV=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The database parameters are set via [environment variable](https://docs.chain.link/docs/connecting-to-a-remote-database/#set-your--database_url-environment-variable)

Comment: I follow this youtube video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB3GLtQvgME&t=2278s
I did have a .env but it is not reading from there.
<code>
ETH_URL=wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/
FEATURE_EXTERNAL_INITIATORS=true
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=42
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost:5432/kovan_demo?sslmode=disable
DATABASE_TIMEOUT=0
FEATURE_FLUX_MONITOR=true
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT=0
CHAINLINK_DEV=true
</code>

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database locally via 
`psql -d kovan_demo -h localhost`

Comment: Yes
    `$ psql -d kovan_demo -h localhost
    psql (14.2)
    Type "help" for help.

    kovan_demo=#`

Comment: I also get `opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=root database=kovan_demo`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)` when I `docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:1.1.1 local n
`

Answer (score 0):

As Richard said, you need to set `DATABASE_URL` as an environment variable. For some reason, the chainlink client cannot read file `.env` and set the environment variable as expected.

The way how I solve the problem is to set `DATABASE_URL` as an environment variable explicitly by command:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://<usrname>:<passswd>@localhost:5432/chainlink_node?sslmode=disable
```

You can find all configurations of Chainlink node [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#essential-environment-variables).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The format to connect to the database is the following:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$SERVER:$PORT/$DATABASE
```

I always follow this steps to create the database:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
create database $DATABASE;
create user $USERNAME with encrypted password '$PASSWORD';
grant all privileges on database $DATABASE to $USERNAME;
```

Just change the variables

```
sudo -u postgres psql
create database chainlink;
create user username with encrypted password 'pass';
grant all privileges on database chainlink to username;
```

And then:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:pass@localhost:5432/chainlink?sslmode=disable
```

I don't recommend at all this credentials for production.

Comment: This is what happened if I use Docker: 
`opening db: failed to open db: failed to connect to 'host=localhost user=username database=chainlink': dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)`

Comment: Same original error without the use of Docker.

Comment: When you are started the chainlink node with docker, did you set this flag `--network host`?
Try something like: `cd ~/.chainlink-rinkeby && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env --network host smartcontract/chainlink:<version> local n`